# Redirect user after authentication to a page that requires a parameter in fortify

Tags: laravel

when a user logs in I want to redirect them to their dashboard page this page requires a param inside of it's route

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(static function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard/{user}', static function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name("dashboard.index");
});
```

In the RouteServiceProvider from fortify itself I tried changing the route a user redirects to to

```
    public const HOME = '/dashboard/'. Auth::id();.;
```

But this unfortunatly does not work, and the docs on fortify / jetstream are limited.

How would I go about changing this ?

Comment: Try `Auth::user()` instead of `Auth::id();`

Comment: Out of interest, why are you defining your group functions as static?

Comment: PHPStorm reccommends declaring these closures as static to "improve performance and better scoping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside LoginController, remove `protected string $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`, then add the following method:

```
public function authenticated()
{
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index', Auth::user());
}
```

This will redirect the user upon successful login to the named route that you've defined as `dashboard.index` with the user model, disregard my comment, you cannot define an expression inside a constant like that

**Edit:**
You have written `return view('dashboard');` which doesn't actually take a `User` so this is actually redundant code?

You should update this route to point to a controller method which requires `User $user` as a parameter. So you'd update your route to look like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard/{user}', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name("dashboard.index");
});
```

**OR**

Re-write the function in LoginController to as follows:

```
public function authenticated()
{
    return view('dashboard', ['user => Auth::user()]);
}
```

This will give you `$user` in your dashboard view.